# Access qualifier for NSBlock is copy or weak or strong?

Tags: ios, objective-c-blocks

I have view controller 1 let's say **VC1** and I am pushing my another view controller let's say **VC2**.

1. In **VC1** I have type defined my block as follow

   `#define typedef void(^Myblock)();`
2. In **VC2** I have declared a block as property as follow

   `@property(nonatomic, weak) MyBlock myBlock;`
3. Before push **VC2** I am assigning a block literal as follow

> ```
>  -(void)pushVC2
>    {
>         __weak VC1 *weakSelf = self;
>         VC2 *vc2 = [self.storyboard instantiateViewControllerWithIdentifier:@"VC2"];
>        [vc2 setMyBlock:^{
>            NSLog(@"Block executed");
>        }];
>     }
> ```

4. My problem is, **the block is not executed** if I called my block from **VC2**. *if I declared the property as copy then block is executed*. Any one has the explanation for this.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Hope this will clear you concept :-

**Note:** You should specify copy as the property attribute, because a block needs to be copied to keep track of its captured state outside of the original scope. This isn’t something you need to worry about when using Automatic Reference Counting, as it will happen automatically, but it’s best practice for the property attribute to show the resultant behavior. For more information, see Blocks Programming Topics.

Source : - https://developer.apple.com/library/ios/documentation/cocoa/conceptual/ProgrammingWithObjectiveC/WorkingwithBlocks/WorkingwithBlocks.html

Comment: Is this("You should specify copy as the property attribute") specified in apple document? Can you please post the exact statement from apple?